# ClientWebsocket in BackgroundService(IHostedService) stops working silently

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, websocket, concurrency

I have a problem where my client websocket implementation within my ASP NET Core web application hosted in an Azure as a App Service stops working after an irregular amount of time.

The implementation is based on a [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) that is run on startup.

```
public class MyService : BackgroundService
{
    public IServiceProvider _services { get; }

    public MyService(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var fortnoxKeys = new List<string>();
        
        using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
        {
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            if (userManager == null)
            {
                throw e;
            }

            fortnoxKeys = FortnoxHelper.getAllFortnoxKeys(userManager);
        }

        var client = new FortnoxWebSocketClient("MY-KEY");
        await client.Connect();

        await client.AddTenant(fortnoxKeys);
        var addTenantResponse = await client.Receive();
        
        await client.AddTopic(WebSocketTopic.Orders);
        var addTopicResponse = await client.Receive();

        await client.Subscribe();
        var subscribeResponse = await client.Receive();

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var Listen = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var response = await client.Receive();

                    if (response.Type == WebSocketResponseType.EventResponse)
                    {
                        if (response.EventType == WebSocketEventType.OrderCreated)
                        {

                          try
                          {
                              // Do work
                          }
                          catch (Exception e)
                          {
                              continue;
                          }

                          // Do more work
                        }
                    }
                    else if (response.Type == WebSocketResponseType.CommandResponse)
                    {
                    }
                }
            });

            var Update = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // Do work and decide which tenants to remove and which to add
                    await client.RemoveTenant(tenantId);
                    // ...
                    await client.AddTenant(newFortnoxKeys);
                }
            });

            Task.WaitAll(Update, Listen);
        }
    }
}
```

This service is injected as a singleton within Startup.cs the reason behind it being a singleton is because I want only a single instance of this websocket client to be run.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyService>();
```

The idea behind the implementation is for this to run forever. Listening to messages and occasionaly update the websocket within the Update task. However this only works for an irregular amount of time. One time it works for 1 day and next time it works for 20 days before it stops recieving messages.

The FortnoxWebSocketClient is a wrapper for the [ClientWebsocket Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=net-5.0) and the source code for it can be found [here](https://github.com/zenta-ab/fortnox.NET/blob/master/Fortnox.NET/WebSockets/FortnoxWebSocketClient.cs)

I have tried upgrading the App Service plan to Standard because I thought it might be the resource recycling in Azure that was the problem but this was unsuccessfull. I have also set the "Always on" flag in Azure to On. In our Azure logs we can see the following message after a certain amount of downtime:

> Heartbeat took longer than "00:00:01" at "03/11/2021 04:09:49 +00:00"

Comment: Is "Always On" set to true? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-general-settings

Comment: @PeterBons Yes it is, that is one of the things I tried together with upgrading the service plan. I forgot to mention it in the original post but have added it now. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you want a continuous WebJob rather than a `BackgroundService` in a WebApp.

Comment: Im looking to solve the exact same problem with fortnox. Did find a solution ?

Comment: @nios What I found out is basically that you cannot assume that your WebSocket connection to Fortnox is going to be kept alive. What I mean with this is that you will most likely have to implement some sort of reconnecting functionality where your service notices downtime and recovers from it. If you ever find a better solution to this I am all ears.

Comment: @BrokenProgrammer I have begun implementation for testing pruposes. But i'll also need to manage a lot of state and persist some stuff in DB to be able to resume functionality after service restarts or connection breaks. This is something that i was somewhat aware of already, but my consern is mostly about the BackgroundJob itself since i have never used it and dont know the reliability of it or if it's even a good option

Comment: @BrokenProgrammer Also i  have a   while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) surrounding everything inside ExecuteAsync. So if anything fails it will hopefully just go into it again, hence the need for me to persist some state to set everything up again after a lost connection or some other error.

Comment: @BrokenProgrammer another thing is tought about with regards to fortnox:es websockets. You do set up your subscribers with a per teenant Bearer token, will they stop sending updates about that tenant when that token expires? Its pretty poorly documented on their site overall.

Comment: @nios This has all been trial & error for me but from my understanding the websocket does not stop sending messages after the Bearer token has expired. I think you are fine with caching  the tenant id and like I said just update theese when you are recovering from a lost connection.